# MySQL sort with different values

Tags: mysql

I have a following table that used to store purchases & issues of items.

```
+-----------+-----+------------+----------+
| Item_name | qty | unit_price |  status  |
+-----------+-----+------------+----------+
| A4        | 180 |        560 | purchase |
| A4        | -15 |        560 | issue    |
| A4        | -10 |        560 | issue    |
| A4        | 200 |        580 | purchase |
| A4        | -25 |        580 | issue    |
| A4        |  -8 |        560 | issue    |
+-----------+-----+------------+----------+
```

purchases are denoted by "purchase" & issues are denoted by "issues" with (-) in the status column.

Then I need to get the balances after performing operations with price differences as follows :

```
+-----------+-----+------------+
| Item_name | qty | unit_price |
+-----------+-----+------------+
| A4        | 147 |        560 |
| A4        | 175 |        580 |
+-----------+-----+------------+
```

I used the following query to do that

```
select item_name, sum(qty) as qty, unit_price from stock group by item_name, unit_price
```

But the query outs only the first record of desired output as follows :

```
+-----------+-----+------------+
| Item_name | qty | unit_price |
+-----------+-----+------------+
| A4        | 147 |        560 |
+-----------+-----+------------+
```

What may be going wrong in my query ? Can anyone help me ?

## Edited Query

```
$this->db->select("store_item.item_name,sum(qty) as qty, unit_price");
        $this->db->from('store_update_stock_details');
        $this->db->join('store_update_stock', 'store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id=store_update_stock.update_stock_id');
        $this->db->join('store_item', 'store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id', 'right');           

        $this->db->where("store_update_stock.status=1 and store_item.item_id= 1");           
        $this->db->group_by('store_item.item_id', 'store_update_stock_details.unit_price');
```

Comment: According to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d337823f6310c5c84ffdcf0f25121ae6 the query is correct. Could you please provide an example where it doesn't work

Comment: @JanezKuhar `select *` for a query with `group by` makes no sense.

Comment: @ nbk. My above question is mentioned in very simply. But the real query as edited.If I set the item_id as 1 which item_name="A4", the query outs one row

Comment: @  zerkms. See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select item_name, sum(qty) as qty, unit_price from stock group by unit_price
```

Group by `Item_name` will aggregate all rows with `Item_name` as `A4` into one row.

Your desired output includes 2 rows with `Item_name` as `A4`

EDIT

```
select item_name, sum(qty) as qty, unit_price from stock group by item_id, unit_price
```

Updated query with more than one item, selecting id instead of name.

Comment: You query only wotks because, he posted only one itemname, test yoir quey with two or more and you will see why the original query has also item_name as Group  by clause

Comment: @nbk You are right, updated to group by item_id as well

Comment: @MCITTrends If you are selecting one item at a time, the first answer works faster. However, like your edited query, group item_id works for multiple items as well.